# Identify an Integrated Circuit MIX3018

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet

I want to ask if the info on the second row (see IC image attached) is relevant or not?

I have a record player circuit with this IC in it:

first row: MIX3018;     , second row:
CRc70A2

It is a 3W Stereo Class-F Audio Power Amplifier. I want to buy a replacement. But I don't know what the info on the second row is, or if it's relevant (when I google it I get a lot of examples of MIX3018, all with different info on the second row, i.e CRc8g1T - on attached photo)
[image: MIX3018 picture]
The  datasheet is mostly in Chinese [Datasheet link](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1299607/Mixinno/MIX3018/1)

Comment: "CRc8g1T" is extremely likely to be a date and/or batch code, and so not relavent for finding a replacement.  In passing, Google translate does a pretty good job on the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet mentions nothing about the markings on the second row.

Therefore the MIX3018 name must be enough and every MIX3018 chip is compatible.

The second row usually consists of chip manufacturing date, lot code, or other tracking info, which is not relevant at all for using the chip.